# ODATA - WebApi: Patch Request for multiple entities

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to call the following PATCH endpoint of my controller (ARRAY of Integers as Keys):

`public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int[] ids, Data data)`

but I am getting from the server the response 404 not found.

I want to update the data for all entities whose id is in the array `ids`.

I am calling the service like that: `http://localhost/appc/odata/MyEntity(13,10)`

MapHttpRoute:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "DefaultApi",
        "api/{controller}/{id}",
        new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    );
```

Any idea why is the route not found?

Comment: The route is not found because this is not something OData supports (a PATCH request with >1 key). Perhaps you should take a look at OData batching (`POST /$batch`) operations.

Comment: ok it is not supported. I find nothing about that in the documentation. So you recommend to do that with POST /$batch. It is a good info,thanks

Comment: unfamiliar with OData in particular but in other areas of .net you can simply pass in multiple query string params with the same key and .net will serialize it as an array/list/collection `myurl.com?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3&ids=4`